# Определить расположение курсора в блоке

Tags: javascript, html, mvc

Есть события `onmouseover` и `onmouseout`, работающие в блоке `div`, НО эти события отрабатывают даже если внутри этого блока есть дочерние элементы, что логично.

А мне нужно знать ФАКТИЧЕСКОЕ расположение курсора в этом блоке (вышел он из него или нет), НЕ ВЗИРАЯ НА ДРУГИЕ ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ.

Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Минус потому что: **1.** в вопросе отсутствует код с проблемой, и/или разметка с внятным описанием желаемого результата; **2.** трудно читать неграмотный текст (`onmouseover` и `onmouseout` это атрибуты, а не события - и в целом, события не "работают/отрабатывают". Надо понимать те сущности с которыми имеешь дело, такое понимание автоматически ответит на большинство вопросов и решит большинство проблем). Надеюсь, это поможет улучшить данный вопрос, и последующие.

Comment: Почитать о событиях, атрибутах задающих их обработчики, прослушивании событий, их всплытии/захвате, отмене и остановке - можно тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/События

Comment: 1. Я хотел вообще понять как это можно реализовать

Comment: 2. Событие onmouseover http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onmouseover меня обманули????

Comment: Да, обманули. На всяких htmlbook'ах, w3fools, и подобных - уж точно не стоит искать правды. Достоверная инфа всегда в оф. спецификациях (и на MDN, хотя и там изредка встречаются ошибки перевода). А реализация зависит от твоей задачи, которая пока что не совсем ясно изложена. В целом, такое решается проверкой свойства `target` экземпляра события (или на точное соответствие, или через `instanceof`/`matches`). Добавив в вопрос хотя бы разметку, ты увеличишь шансы на получение точного ответа с кодом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно стоит использовать другие события?
mouseenter, mouseleave
https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave#sobytiya-mouseenter-i-mouseleave

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек

Answer (score 0):

Общее решение, пока вопрос недостаточно конкретен:

```js
const foo = document.querySelector('.foo'); 
for (const evt of ['mouseover', 'mouseout']) 
  foo.addEventListener(evt, handlerFunc); 

function handlerFunc(evt) {
  const listeningEl = evt.currentTarget, 
        hover = (evt.target === listeningEl) && (evt.type === 'mouseover'); 
  listeningEl.classList.toggle('highlight', hover); 
}
```

```css
body, div { padding: 2rem; }
.foo {
  display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between; align-items: center; 
  background: #eee; }
.foo > * { flex: 1 1; margin: 0 1rem; background: #4d4; }
.highlight { background: #ff0 !important; }
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```